# Finding the determinant of linear transformations from the space of $2 \times 2$ upper triangular matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant, linear-transformations

Find the determinant of the linear transformation
$$ T(M) = 
\begin{bmatrix}
3 && -3 \\
0 && 9
\end{bmatrix}M
 $$
from the space $V$ of upper triangular $2 \times 2$ matrices to $V$.

Comment: What are your thoughts on the problem? What have you tried and where did you get stuck?

Comment: All I know about this problem is that a determinant of a triangular matrix is the product along the diagonal entries. Which basically gives me (3)(9)*(a)(d) where you have M being $ \begin{bmatrix} a && b \\ c && d \end{bmatrix}$

Comment: That's not what your question is about though. It's about the determinant of a linear map from $V$ to $V$. What is the dimension of $V$?

Comment: No. The dimension is $3$. Why?

Comment: My mistake, I deleted quickly as I realized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A basis for the space of $2\times2$ upper triangular matrices is given by
$$e_1:=\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&0\end{pmatrix},\qquad e_2:=\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\0&0\end{pmatrix},\qquad e_3:=\begin{pmatrix}0&0\\0&1\end{pmatrix}.$$
and a few simple calculations show that
$$T(e_1)=3e_1,\qquad T(e_2)=3e_2,\qquad T(e_3)=-3e_2+9e_3.$$
So with respect to this basis the linear map $T$ is given by
$$\begin{pmatrix}3&0&0\\0&3&-3\\0&0&9\end{pmatrix},$$
so the determinant of $T$ is $81$.

Comment: Thanks, I already forgot to do the basics with linear transformations by just finding the basis.

Comment: Because $T(e_2)=\begin{pmatrix}3&-3\\0&9\end{pmatrix}e_2=3e_2$, just do the matrix multiplications.

Comment: I just deleted, sorry I didn't check on paper first so I didn't see at first glance. Thanks for the help, I see the computations.

Comment: Tip: Multiplying a matrix by the $i$-th standard basis vector yields the $i$-th column of that matrix. Once you know that, no computations are needed for the matrix multiplications above.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way that relies on the equality $\det T = \prod_k \lambda_k$.

The eigenvalues are solutions to $T(M) = \lambda M $, with $M \neq 0$.

If we write $T(M) = AM$, we are looking for solutions to
$(\lambda I -A ) M = 0$. Expanding shows that we must have $\lambda \in \{3,9\}$,
and substituting these values shows that $\ker (3I -T)$ has dimension two
and $\ker (9I -T)$ has dimension one, hence $\det T = 3^2 9 = 81$.

Note that $\ker (3I -T) = \operatorname{sp} \{ 
\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0\end{bmatrix},
\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0\end{bmatrix} \}$, and
$\ker (9I -T) = \operatorname{sp} \{ 
\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 0 & -2\end{bmatrix} \}$.

This follows from Servaes' observation that if $(\lambda I -A) M = 0$ then
the columns of $M$ must be eigenvectors of $A$.

Keep in mind that the dimensions are computed with $M$ being upper triangular.

Comment: An alternative to expanding is realizing that the columns of $M$ must come from eigenspaces of $A=\begin{pmatrix}3&-3\\0&9\end{pmatrix}$, so $\lambda\in\{3,9\}$.

Comment: By the way, it is not true that $\dim\ker(3I-A)=2$.

Comment: This seems like an abuse of notation, or you are confusing $A$ and $T$; clearly
$$\dim\ker(3I-A)=\dim\ker\begin{pmatrix}0&3\\0&-6\end{pmatrix}=1.$$
What I think you want to say is that $\dim\ker(3\operatorname{id}_V-T)=2$.

Comment: @Servaes: Oops, I meant $T$ , not $A$.

Comment: It's also worth distinguishing between $I=\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&1\end{pmatrix}\in V$ and $\operatorname{id}_V:\ V\ \longrightarrow\ V$, as the difference between elements of $V$ and linear transformations of $V$ seems to be a source of confusion, and the reason for this question to begin with.

Comment: @Servaes: That's abuse of a different sort :-).